# Is the Ford Fiesta 2008, style climate D, 1.4 TDCi engine made by Peugeot?

Tags: ford, fiesta

Is the engine made by Peugeot or Ford? Apparently if it's Peugeot, it could be prone to the turbo failing due to engine fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the engine was designed by Peugeot/Citroen (PSA) but made by Ford in Ford’s London factory.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSA_HDi_engine and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_Duratorq_engine and

Comment: Wiki suggests half made at ford factories, half at psa. But doesn't say I the TDCi ones are always made at ford.

Comment: Ian, could you edit the answer to include the relevant parts of the wiki into the answer? Thanks

Comment: @Zaid, wiki does not have any solid information on the answer, just background.   Hopefully someone else will have a better source of information that has more details.

Comment: Would be good to know, if I'd known it was a Peugeot engine I wouldn't have bought it.